# How to use the aux file

Tags: auxiliary-files

This is not a terribly well-formed question, sorry. I don't really know what information is in the .aux file, or how I can make use of it in other (related) documents. What's the best reference for understanding how this works?

One common thing I would like to be able to do is the following: I have a book that contains lots of `\label`s. I would like to be able to reference those labels from the solutions manual, which is separately created (as a .tex file) and generated (as a PDF).

Comment: I have a feeling this question should be two separate questions. Or it should ask about the second part and add the first as a guess what might be the direction of the solution; this would require a different question title though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to know what is in the aux-file: Open it in an editor and look it up. 
Actually every package (and you too) can write something to the aux-file if it want. So the aux-file normally contains quite a lot informations which are very document specific and which would cause troubles in another document.

So if you want to read an external aux-file you must be careful. E.g. an aux-file contains lines which should be written to the toc-file (`\@writefile{toc}`) which you don't want to process in this case. The xr-package mentioned by Boris e.g. loops through external `aux`-files and looks for `\newlabel` commands but ignores everything else.

Answer (score 20):

I think you need the package [xr](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xr) - it allows one `tex` file to use eXternal References, defined in the `.aux` file of another `tex` file